# How to close a QFileDialog.getOpenFileName in QTest?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am developing an application in Python 3.5, using PyQt4, and I want to test it with unit test using QTest. So far I managed to do whatever I want with QTest except for this problem :

My window as a folder button, when you click it, a File Dialog open to choose a folder (classic). This is (more or less) written like that in my code :

```
self.file_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
[...]    
tmp_path = self.file_dialog.getOpenFileName(self, caption='toto', filter="*.csv")
```

My problem is that in QTest, I can't find a way to close this dialog when it shows up.

I already tried calling its close() or reject() method (directly or with a single shot timer), but none of these seems to work...

Is there any solution I didn't thought of ? I wouldn't mind closing all windows if that's necessary (but I can't do that either)

Thanks !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by close the dialog when it shows up. Do you mean you want the program to automatically close the dialog or do you mean that as a user when the dialog opens you can't close it manually?

Comment: I want the program to automatically close the dialog, because so far the dialog shows up and the tests are stopped until I manually close it. I would like to be able to automatically launch those tests (once a week by exemple), without any manual operation needed. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I have understood, you should not use the static methods (such as `getOpenFileName`) in tests, because you cannot control the opening of the dialog window. You should instead use the constructor, set the options you need and then call `self.file_dialog.exec_()` only in the real code (not in the tests).